# Xcode references wrong path to Mono

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin, mono, embeddinator

I'm trying to compile the c code generated by [Embeddinator-4000](https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000) but Xcode can't find the specified path to Mono.

These are the headers that are currently giving me problems:

```
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/mono-config.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>
#include <mono/metadata/debug-helpers.h>
#include <mono/metadata/object.h>
```

However these paths work:

```
#include <Mono/mono-2.0/mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <Mono/mono-2.0/mono/metadata/mono-config.h>
#include <Mono/mono-2.0/mono/metadata/assembly.h>
#include <Mono/mono-2.0/mono/metadata/debug-helpers.h>
#include <Mono/mono-2.0/mono/metadata/object.h>
```

The problem is that `jit.h` includes `<mono/metadata/appdomain.h>` and Xcode can't find it.

Is there a way to alias the framework so I don't have to modify my current install of Mono?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add your `framework` in the `Embedded Binary` section in `Xcode`? You can refer:[dotnet-embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/get-started/objective-c/ios)

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT The `objcgen` command gave me an error (`The feature Returning type Action from native code is not currently supported by the tool`) so I tried running `mono Embeddinator-4000.exe my.dll --gen=Swift -p iOS -o output --static` which output swift and c files that I'm trying to compile.